# difference between Linesets and Linestyle?

Tags: freestyle

I wondering what is difference between Linesets and Linstyle.
in first, I think Linestyle is nested from Linesets, but it seems not.
I understand LineStyle is to change style or form of Freestyle Line
LineSets for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got it, a lineset is a complete "set" of properties, and also has one of the available linestyles, amongst many other indipendent properties and settings.

You can make each lineset behave in a way that it's applied to different rendering "selection methods".

By "selection methods" you can choose one or more of visibility, edgetypes, facemarks, groups and image border.

Eg: the simplest to explain an understand is perhaps groups: you could have two cubes, each has its own group. Then you can make the cube of Group1 to have a totally different "lineset" than the other, using two of them, each targeted to a particular group, like this:

[image]

while the other cube has a different group and, thus, a different lineset, which also has different linestyle (but is not mandatory: it could have same linestyle, but behave differently from the other lineset for other settings...)

[image]

Comment: this is what I am searching for answer! =) in my work,almost comic, various object in one scene want to have each line style. this explanation  solve the problem!

Comment: Good! :) I just used the "group" selection method, above, by far the simplest, you should read carefully the manual pages about freestyle, like https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html. I used freestyle just a bit, but sometimes it's tricky to get desired results for several objects with different linesets...

Comment: probably, I focused on visibility effect or edge type and took no notice group section in line set. then missed aim of line set function. anyway, I am grad to meet good answer!